# Show that chordal metric is topologically equivalent to the Euclidean metric

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, geometric-topology

Consider
$$d(x,y)=\frac{2\|x-y\|}{(1+\|x\|^2)^{1/2}(1+\|y\|^2)^{1/2}},\hspace{5mm}x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n.$$
$d$ is a metric in $\mathbb{R}^n$ known as *chordal metric*. I want to show that this metric is topologically equivalent to the Euclidean metric $\|x-y\|$.
In order to do this, I tried to find positive real constants $M,N$ such that
$$M\cdot d(x,y)\leq \|x-y\|\leq N\cdot d(x,y),\forall x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n.$$
It's trivial to see that
$$\frac{1}{2}d(x,y)\leq \|x-y\|$$
finding, for instance, $M=1/2$. But I don't know how to find such $N$ as above!

Any idea? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You're not going to find the number $N$ independent of $x,y$.  That's easy to see: take $x,y$ at a very, very large distance from the origin (making the denominator large), and satisfying $||x-y||=1$.

However, you don't need something that strong, because $N$ can be allowed to depend on $x$ and $y$ in some fashion. For instance, it would certainly suffice if for all $x$ you could find $N_x$ such that for all $y$ in a ball of radius $1$ around $x$, the second inequality holds using the constant $N_x$.

Comment: Yes, that was my doubt! I've found such $N_x$, but why is this sufficient? Is this a basic result? I'm kinda beginner on topology, so... :P
@LeeMosher

Comment: Let $A$ be open with respect to the Euclidean metric and $x_0\in A$, with $\varepsilon>0$ such that $\|x-x_0\|<\varepsilon \implies x\in A$. We have then that
$$d(x,x_0)=\frac{2\|x-x_0\|}{(1+\|x\|^2)^{1/2}(1+\|x_0\|^2)^{1/2}}<N_x \varepsilon \implies x\in A.$$
where $N_x=\frac{2}{(1+\|x\|^2)^{1/2}(1+\|x_0\|^2)^{1/2}}$. Is this you are talking about? @LeeMosher

Comment: Assuming you know the definition of "topological equivalence" of metrics, the proof that this suffices is an exercise.